# How to prevent context consumers re-rendering when only irrelevant parts of the context have changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm managing global state with `useReducer` in a root-level wrapper, which renders its children inside a context provider in the typical way:

```
return (
  <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
    {children}
  </GlobalContext.Provider>
)
```

So descendents can do `const { state } = useContext()` to get the context, and this means they automatically re-render whenever `state` changes.

Let's say `state` has three values, `a`, `b`, and `c`. If a state consumer only cares about `a`, how can I prevent it wastefully re-rendering when only `b` or `c` have changed?

One way is to pass each state value (and the dispatch function) through its own separate context:

```
return (
  <AContext.Provider value={state.a}>
    <BContext.Provider value={state.b}>
      <CContext.Provider value={state.c}>
        <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          {children}
        </DispatchContext.Provider>
      </CContext.Provider>
    </BContext.Provider>
  </AContext.Provider>
)
```

But that looks clunky, and it makes consumption more fiddly for components that need multiple state values. And this would quickly worsen as your app's state grows in complexity.

Is there a better way?